# ASP.NET Core use (Json Web Token) JWT to authenticate a session

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, razor-pages

i am trying to add authentication with JWT to my razor pages web application. I want the user to enter his emailadress and then ill check if the email exists in my database. If the address is stored in the database i want to create a token and store it in a session.

i have not found anything on stackoverflow/youtube/internet about how to implement something like this with razorpages. So do you have some ideas how i could setup this with razor pages?

I tried to follow some tutorial but nothing realy worked out.

**1. My program.cs is configured  like this.**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            o.SaveToken = true;
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:Key"])),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();
```

**2. My post mehtod which is called after pressing the login buttin looks like this. In this mehtod i want to store the token in a session or cookies.**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {   
            await _loginRepository.CreateToken(Email);
//TODO store token here
            return RedirectToPage("/Picture/Index");
        }
```

After i check if the email exists i am generation a token and then redirect to a page which is Protected by `[Autroize(Roles = "Admin")]`.

3. my token generation

   ```
   public async Task<bool> CreateToken(string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var journalists = await _zentralContext.v_PressInfo_Journalisten.Select(s => s.Email).ToListAsync();
        if (journalists.Contains(email))
        {    
            var journalist = await _zentralContext.v_PressInfo_Journalisten.Where(w => w.Email == email).FirstAsync();
            var token = CreateToken(email);
            //Store Token here??
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private string CreateToken(string email)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TheSecretKeyNeedsToBePrettyLongSoWeNeedToAddSomeCharsHere"));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
        };
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "Presseinfo Extern",
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            signingCredentials: creds);
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, It seems you want to store the generated token into session in your Login repository. So You can refer to this simple demo.

Register `HttpContextAccessor` in your dependency inject container:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Inject this into your repository:

```
public class LoginRepository : IloginRepository
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public LoginRepository(MyDbContext myDbContext, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _myDbContext = myDbContext;
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateToken(string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result =await _myDbContext.loginModels.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);
            if (result != null)
            {
                var token = CreateToken(email);
                _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", token);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private string CreateToken(string email)
        {
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TheSecretKeyNeedsToBePrettyLongSoWeNeedToAddSomeCharsHere"));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            };
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "Presseinfo Extern",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: creds);
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

Now If the email address is stored in the database, your project will generate a token and store it into session.

Ps: don't forget to configure session in your project, you can refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Do i have to check the Token string in the Middleware then?

Comment: @flomue99,
Sorry i don't get your point, authentication middleware will check this token.

Comment: sry for this, i am new in this. I mean do i have to check the token here now.  `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {`

Comment: oh I get your point, you don't need to create another middleware to validate token, `app.UseAuthentication();` will validate it, please note that `app.UseAuthentication();` need to place before `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Comment: I have updatet my code, but still getting 401 Error at pages with [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: had a spelling mistake, Tahnk your for your Help!!